# Show that every nearly paracompact space is almost paracompact but the converse is not true

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, topological-groups

I am learning about the nearly para-compact space and almost para-compact space. I know that every nearly para-compact space is almost para-compact space but the converse is not true in general. So i need an example of almost para-compact space which is not nearly para-compact space.

Answer (score 0):

You really should think a bit harder about the examples that you’ve already received. Just in the case of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1714167/show-that-every-paracompact-space-is-nearly-paracompact-but-the-converse-is-not/1714181#1714181), one of them answers the present question: the space described in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1698870/12042) is almost compact, hence almost paracompact, and the same open cover that **user87690** used to show that it is not nearly compact works to show that it is not nearly paracompact, either.